# Ajax submission on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a test script for a small little website I'm doing, and it requires a lot of troubleshooting with this particular form. In order to get a response, I need to fill out 5 step form wizard and then wait for the results. I've been trying to create a small little script I can use on a seperate page to test my php functions in a heartbeat. Here is what I have so far, and it doesn't seem to even post to the page.

```
<div id="response"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = {
        console: "playstation",
        game: "FIFA14",
        coinamount: "10000",
        team: "Some Team Name",
        league: "Some League Name",
        player: "Some Player Name",
        quality: "Silver",
        chemistry: "Basic",
        position: "CAM",
        customername: "Joey Small",
        customeremail: "jsmall@email.com",
        customerphonenumber: "23454343534",
        payment: "pp"
    }
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "order.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:  function(data){
        $("#response").html(data);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

I'm inspecting the network data in my browser, and it is not sending to order.php. I don't have much love for javascript, especially Jquery, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is your content type false?  It takes a string type..

Comment: In all honesty, I used an example from the Jquery website. I stated that I don't have much love for javascript, and only use it when I absolutely have to.

Comment: I don't see any example on the `.ajax()` page that uses a contentType of false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the additional options added on to the end are what is making the script not submit.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "order.php",
    data: data,
    success:  function(data){
        //alert("---"+data);
        $("#response").html(data);
    }
});
```

That works correctly. Daedalus's comment got me to thinking about the additional tags, and how they are not needed.

Comment: I needed too wait two days before I was allowed to mark my own answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

first thing you should do is close the script tag on your Jquery include at the top

Comment: I might have did something weird with the formatting here, but my script has all required tags.

Comment: As your answer is not an answer you'd better post this as a comment (maybe you can't due to your rep :/, but keep this in mind ;) )